# red close button event

Tags: c#, winforms, window

What is the event that a function will be triggered when the user is clicking on the red close button.
I need to create a little lets name it log item when thiss happens in a txt file.

I searched but didn't find any solution

```
private void Window_Closing1(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)
{

}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onclosing?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: What are you targeting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Btw: The button is red only on some (I believe older) windows versions..

Answer (score 1):

There is no event that is linked to the user clicking that *Close* button specifically. A form has `Closing` and `Closed` events, but they're pretty much obsolete these days and have been superseded by the `FormClosing` and `FormClosed` events.

`FormClosing` is raised before the form closes and allows you to prevent it closing. `FormClosed` is raised after the form has closed. Both events provide an `e.CloseReason` property that gives you more specific information on how the form was closed. That property would be `UserClosing` if the user clicked the *Close* button on the title bar, but there are other methods that would result in the same value.

Comment: _"There is no event that is linked to the user clicking that Close button specifically."_ - I'd say NET's behaviour pretty much mimics _native code._   _["`WM_CLOSE` - Sent as a signal that a window or an application should terminate.  An application can prompt the user for confirmation, prior to destroying a window, by processing the WM_CLOSE message and calling the DestroyWindow function only if the user confirms the choice.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close)_

Comment: @MickyD, I'm not really sure what you're trying to tell me specifically. `WM_CLOSE` is a Windows message, not an event, and the window will receive it under various circumstances, not just when the user clicks the Close button. If you want to recommend that the OP intercepts a Windows message then you probably ought to write an answer that explains how to do that. I don't know why that's a comment on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, there is no built-in event in the `Form` class. However, you can intercept the [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) message on [`Form.WndProc(ref Message m)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and check if the `Message.WParam` is equal to `SC_CLOSE` to catch the event at which the window close button is clicked. Optionally, you can have a special event named `CloseButtonClick` and raise the event.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExampleApp
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public event EventHandler CloseButtonClick;

        private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        private IntPtr SC_CLOSE = new IntPtr(0xF060);

        // When you inherite from this class, for a good practice, you should override this method to catch the event with calling base definition.
        protected virtual void OnCloseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if(CloseButtonClick != null)
                CloseButtonClick(sender, args);
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if(m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
            {
                if (m.WParam == SC_CLOSE)
                    OnCloseButtonClick(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

    }
}
```